# prove that $P(A\cup B)\cdot P(A'\cap B')\leq P(C)$.

Tags: probability

> If $A,B$ are $2$ independent events, prove that $P(A\cup B)\cdot P(A'\cap B')\leq P(C)$.
>
> where $C$ is an event defined that exactly one of $A$ and $B$ occur.

Try: For $2$ Independent events $A$ and $B$, $A',B'$ are also Independent

So $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ and $P(A'\cap B')=P(A')P(B')$

and ecactly one of $A$ and $B$ occur is

$P(C)=P(A)P(B')+P(A')P(B)$

Now comes to the left side of question

$P(A\cup B)\cdot P(A'\cap B')=\bigg(P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)\bigg)(P(A')P(B'))$

Could some help me please to solve it from that point  , Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are almost done, right? Note that 
\begin{align*}
\left[P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)\right]P(A')P(B')&\le [P(A)+P(B)]P(A')P(B')\\
&=P(A)P(B')P(A')+P(A')P(B)P(B')\\
&\le P(A)P(B')+P(B)P(A')\\
&=P(C)
\end{align*}
where the second inequality holds as $P(A'), P(B')\in [0,1]$ while the rest terms are nonnegative.